# Shortcode in woocommerce categories

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode

i want to put shortcode in categories but have only text editor and it's not possible to added. Any idea how to do this ?

[woocatslider id="855"]

Want to show subcategories slider in every main category

I try to put php code for taxonomy but doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Show the code you have tried.